# How to use/consume an event stream from wolkenkit-eventstore

Tags: wolkenkit

I want to use wolkenkit's [eventstore](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-eventstore) and was trying to set up a quick example. But I'm not able to simply output an event stream.

Simplified example:

```
const eventstore = require("wolkenkit-eventstore/inmemory");
const Stream = require("stream");
const uuidv4 = require("uuid/v4");
const Event = require("commands-events/dist/Event");

const main = async () => {
    await eventstore.initialize();

    const aggregateId = uuidv4();
    const event = new Event({ ... });
    event.metadata.revision = 1;

    await eventstore.saveEvents({ events: event });

    const writableStream = new Stream.Writable();
    writableStream._write = (chunk, encoding, next) => {
        console.log(chunk.toString());
                next()
    };

    const readableStream = eventstore.getUnpublishedEventStream();
    readableStream.pipe(writableStream);
};

main();
```

As far as I understand, *getUnpublishedEventStream* returns a readable stream. I followed [this](https://flaviocopes.com/nodejs-streams/) instructions, but it didn't work as expected.
All I get is the following error:

```
(node:10988) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: readableStream.pipe is not a function
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation of wolkenkit-eventstore](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-eventstore#reading-unpublished-events), `getUnpublishedEventStream` is an `async` function, i.e. you have to call it with `await`. Otherwise, you don't get a stream back, but a promise (and a promise doesn't have a `pipe` function).

So, this line

```
const readableStream = eventstore.getUnpublishedEventStream();
```

should be:

```
const readableStream = await eventstore.getUnpublishedEventStream();
```

I have not taken a closer look at your code apart from this, but this is the reason why you get the current error message.

*PS: Please note that I am one of the core developers of wolkenkit, so please take my answer with a grain of salt.*

Comment: Hey Golo, thanks for the quick answer. Sadly you're right, I totally forgot that it's an async method. I should have taken a look into the test folder of the [repo](https://github.com/thenativeweb/wolkenkit-eventstore/tree/master/test) earlier. There I found another package of yours [streamtoarray](https://www.npmjs.com/package/streamtoarray) and think it could be very helpful.